# Make Calculation : <?php echo ''.$Total.'' ?>

Tags: php

How would l take the following  and make a calculation that would be :

TOTAL * 2 / 100 and SHOW in decimal place (£) pounds.

So example 1000 (TOTAL) would be £20.00

Comment: You start by writing a little bit of code... something like `$total = 1000; $result = $total * 2 / 100; echo '£', number_format($result, 2);`

Comment: A google search for 'PHP decimal places' would have got you there.

Answer (score 0):

`&pound;<?php echo number_format( ($total * 2) / 100, 2); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

number_format — Format a number with grouped thousands
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php